# Oracle Mobile setup on Android:

Tags: android, oracle

I have setup the oracle Mobile on Windows Mobile.I am trying to setup those same setup into android phone,Is it possible?If anyboay have done this already? please help me

Comment: According to this, you can, https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2295884 , I assume this is the product you are talking about.

Comment: Yes.Thanks.http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E22663_01/doc.11100/e22681/instsqlite.htm